# Can non-Zerg races build on friendly creep?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

If I'm in a team SC2 game, can my non-Zerg allies build on top of my creep?

Comment: Hah, it would be nice, but that's not the Zerg's philosophy :) They are hostile to other races. I always laughed at the absurdity of the idea of a terran medic in SC1 healing a hydralisk or lurker, or any other interaction between zergs and other races.

Comment: IIRC the Warcraft III creep-like ground cover, the undead "blight," *could* be built on.

Comment: def an issue that has affected me in 2v2 and 3v3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, not last I tried with Terrans and Zerg.

This is particularly bad on one of the 3v3 maps in which there are 2 nice natural expansions right next to each other - if a Zerg ally takes one of them and you're not Zerg, you will need to also take it fast (before the Hatchery spreads just a little creep) or else not be able to at all.

It also makes defending with Bunkers rather difficult if a friendly Zerg starts spreading creep - which is something he really does want to do!

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: Yeah, I used to like that map until I started playing Zerg.  I usually end up double-hatch in the main on that one because I don't want to impede my teammates that are building up defenses.

Comment: Correct, Also, note that there is no such thing as "friendly creep" all creep is just creep. There's nothing distinguishing one player's creep from another player's.